# Google Closure compiler warning for RegExp

Tags: javascript, regex, closures, warnings

When compiling a Javascript file using the Google Closure compiler set for Advanced Optimization, I get the following warning:

WARNING - References to the global RegExp object prevents optimization of regular expressions.

The warning is being triggered by the following line of code, which I believe is fine.

```
        rv = parseFloat( RegExp.$1 );
```

What keyword can I use in a Suppress construct of the following form for suppressing the aforementioned warning:

```
/** @suppress {need_keyword_here} */
```

Answer (score 2):

`/** @suppress {checkRegExp} */` does the trick.

Source: [this list of warnings](https://github.com/google/closure-compiler/wiki/Warnings)

Comment: Doesn't work for me. I'm already using that 'suppress' statement, but continue to see the WARNING mentioned in my question.

Comment: Did you try to put it as a global flag when compiling ? If you don't need RegExp check at all of course.